# How to respond with pre recorded audio in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

In fulfillment option in Dialogflow CX, I am adding a "play pre recorded audio" in Add dialog option and it requires a link of an audio. I have provided it links of different formats but it is not working.

Can you help me with the hosting service for that audio and the format of link? I am using Firebase right now

Answer (score 2):

Note that the audio link must be hosted publicly in order for it to work. You can opt to use Cloud Storage to host your audio file. For more information, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#audio).

I tried this on my end and I was able to play the audio by using the **Public URL** of the audio file. You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) on how to make your data public in Cloud Storage.

Moreover, to test the audio output, you’ll have to test it in an integration that could play audio files. You can either use one of Dialogflow CX’s [built-in telephony integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration) or your own custom integration.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are having issues with native DFCX playback of messages.
I recommend you to use the easy CX Telephony integration by Voximplant.

You can have full control of the playback and also use other Synthetic voices from Amazon, Microsoft and IBM as well as Google Voices.

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kp5haQ7zNQ) about the integration.

Check this link for [Documentation about CX Voice integration](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/integrations/dialogflowcx)